# How to properly access and set class variables in a derived class?

Tags: python, derived-class, class-method, class-variables

Supposed that you have a python class (say `B`) that is a derived class of some other class (say `A`) and that class `A` has both class variables and `@classmethods` that help you change or view these class variables. I had assumed that a `@classmethod` in class `A` that sets a class `A` class variable using the syntax `cls.variable_name = value` would work.

This seems to work sometimes but not always which confuses me. Below is an example that does not set the class variables as I would expect. Therefore I cannot tell what `cls.something` will be accessing and so I have to use `A.something` which seems that I will be missing the capabilities of `cls.something` in `@classmethods`. What does `cls.something` actually access in class methods and why does the following example not set the `test` class class variables?

The following example with output hopefully demonstrates what I mean:

```
class Test():
    epf = 'A'

    @classmethod
    def set_formats(cls, p):
        cls.epf = p

    @classmethod
    def form(cls):
        return cls.epf

class Mytest(Test):
        pass
```

Here is the output:

```
>>>c=Mytest
>>>Test.form()
'A'

>>>c.set_formats(p='a')
>>>Test.epf
'A'

>>>c.form()
'a'

>>>c.epf
'a'
```

So in this example the classmethods are not changing the class variable as I would expect and instead an instance variable seems to appear. If I do the above without a derived class then it works as expected. Hmm? Clearly missing something here!

Now if I change the `c.set_formats(p='a', f='A')` to `Test.set_formats(p='a', f='A')` it does work. Is it because `c.set_formats` uses the class method with `cls` being an instance?

**Edit:** Made the code much smaller and changed conventions as requested.

Comment: You should edit your question to provide a [mre]. There is quite a lot of irrelevant code that makes the central point of your question difficult to distinguish.

Comment: If you invoke a classmethod on a subclass, then the `cls` parameter will be the subclass, not necessarily the class containing the method.

Comment: "Is it because `C.set_formats` uses the class method with `cls` being an instance?" No, `cls` would be **the class of the instance** like it always is with class methods. In this case, it will be the same as `mytest.set_formats(p='a', f='A')`, i.e. it is setting the class variables on `mytest`. The subclass class variables shadow the base class class variables, like always (this *is* inheritance). "So in this example the classmethods are not changing the class variable as I would expect and instead an instance variable seems to appear. " no, check `mytest.epf`

Comment: As an aside, you are using the *complete opposite* and very confusing convention of `lowercase` for the class, and `UpperCase` for the instance. Please dont' do that, it makes your code very confusing to people used to Python, particularly in the context of your question where the classs/instance distinction is crucial

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Made the code much smaller as requested.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have changed the convention as you requested. Thanks for your comment on what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it because `c.set_formats` uses the class method with `cls` being an instance?

Yes, you can check via print calls showing the ids of the involved objects.